# Create image from pixel array in java

Tags: java, image, io, rgb

Here is my snippet. My original array is `a[3][][]` and the rgb values are stored in there I want to create a new image from them. The last line of the following code results in symbol not found.

```
BufferedImage img=newBufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for(int r=0; r<bi.getHeight(); r++)
    for(int c=0; c<bi.getWidth(); c++)
    {
        int red=a[0][r][c];
        int green=a[1][r][c];
        int blue=a[2][r][c];
        int rgb = (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
        img.setRGB(c, r, rgb);
    }
ImageIO.write(img,"jpg", "abc.jpg");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest that you use `{}` on all for loops. It will minimize the risk of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the wrong arguments to `ImageIO.write()`. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html), here are the 3 possibilities:

```
write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, File output) 
write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, ImageOutputStream output) 
write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, OutputStream output)
```

If you want to write the image to a file called `abc.jpg`, maybe try:

```
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("abc.jpg");
```

Comment: On a side note, I agree with Maba, throw `{}` on every loop =)

Comment: Seconded :) . I can't even write loops without `{}` anymore :D .